# typeloadexception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, prism

I get following error when running the application in the emulator. The application builds without errors. Im using VS2015 CE with prism libraries.

> could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane'."

This is how my solution looks like
[image]

And this is where the program stops
[image]

XAML:

```
<prism:MvvmAppBase
    x:Class="MainModule.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MainModule"
    xmlns:prism="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps">

</prism:MvvmAppBase>
```

cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps;



// The Blank Application template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace MainModule
{
    public sealed partial class App : MvvmAppBase
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override Task OnLaunchApplication(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        protected override void OnRegisterKnownTypesForSerialization()
        {
            // Set up the list of known types for the SuspensionManager
            //SessionStateService.RegisterKnownType(typeof(Address));
        }

        protected override void OnInitialize(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            _container.RegisterInstance(NavigationService);
            //_container.RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            //_container.RegisterType<IShippingAddressUserControlViewModel, ShippingAddressUserControlViewModel>();

            //as  function says, it sets default view type to viewmodel, for an example it sets HubViewModel to HubView
            ViewModelLocator.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver((viewType) =>
            {
                var viewModelTypeName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "UIViewModelsLibrary.ViewModels.{0}ViewModel, UIViewModelsLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral", viewType.Name);
                var viewModelType = Type.GetType(viewModelTypeName);
                return viewModelType;
            });
        }

        protected override object Resolve(Type type)
        {
            return _container.Resolve(type);
        }
    }
}
```

And my MainPage files (FacultyPage is almost the same)

Xaml:

```
<prism:VisualStateAwarePage
    x:Class="ViewsLibrary.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ViewsLibrary.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prism="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps" mc:Ignorable="d"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="true"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Go To Faculty" 
            Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</prism:VisualStateAwarePage>
```

cs file:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps;

namespace ViewsLibrary.Views
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : VisualStateAwarePage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps.Interfaces;

namespace UIViewModelsLibrary.ViewModels
{
    class MainViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel(INavigationService navService)
        {

            NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => navService.Navigate("Faculty", null));
        }

        public DelegateCommand NavigateCommand { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I'm a novice in programming for Windows Phone and what I'm trying to do is to create a framework that could be used as a base for some of my apps. But this error has already taken me hours.

Comment: What version of NuGet packages are you using? Your code is not correct for the latest version (Prism.StoreApps 2.0.0).

Comment: yes. im using 1.1.0 version, as i said i'm a novice in windows development and i took this as a reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130642.aspx i also tried 2.0.0 and it seemed that most of classes that im using now were missing but i didnt find any other source on how to use 2.0.0. Is that a concerning flaw in this framework or can i stay on 1.0.0?

Comment: I must be missing something, as 1.1.0 is only for Windows 8, not Windows Phone.